# Refresh page when deleting records

Tags: jquery, datatable, min

I am using datatables.net and while i am deleting the record from any page it will redirect me on first page.

How can I reload the same page whenever I delete any record from any page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you use ajax with datatables and don't do a entire page load. Also, show some code or else we can't help you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please show us some code you are using...and i suppose the row you delete is done using ajax. If correct just catch the return data from ajax and on the function and redraw the table using the draw function.

Comment: how can i use ajax?

Comment: is there any command for that?    I am writing delete button's code in php

Comment: Please show us the code so we can understand how are you deleting the row. Thanks.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
 } );

Comment: $('#example').DataTable( {
     stateSave: true,
     stateLoadCallback: function (settings) {
         var o;
  
               $.ajax( {
             url: 'listrecord.php',
             async: false,
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (json) {
                 o = json;
             }
         } );
  
         return o;
     }
 } );

Comment: @John_rees add your code to the question, not to the comment section.

Comment: Please consider take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Thanks.